# Why does the proxy server use my private IP?

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-proxy

I am trying to scrape using proxies (this proxy server is a free one from the internet); in particular I would like to use their IP, not my private one. To test my script I am trying to Access "http://whatismyipaddress.com/" to see which IP this site sees. As it turns out it will see my private IP. Can somebody tell me what's wrong here?

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

def getMyIP(proxyServer,myPrivateIP):

    scrape_website = "http://whatismyipaddress.com/"

    ua = UserAgent()
    headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(scrape_website,headers=headers,proxies={"https":proxyServer})
    except:
        faultString = proxyServer + " did not work; " + "\n" 
        print(faultString)
        return
    
    if myPrivateIP in str(response.content):
        print("They found my private IP.")

proxyServer = "http://103.250.158.23:61219"
myPrivateIP = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
getMyIP(proxyServer,myPrivateIP)
```

Comment: You only specify an `https` proxy, but make an `http` request…

Comment: The proxy server is pushing forward your IP. There's nothing you can do except for using a different proxy. Although it may be difficult to find such proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You set an `{'https': ...}` proxy configuration. This means for any *HTTPS requests*, it will use that proxy. You're requesting an HTTP URL however, so that proxy isn't getting used. Configure an `'http'` proxy instead or in addition.
2. *If* the proxy forwards your IP in an HTTP header, and the target server heeds that header, that's tough luck and nothing you can do anything about, besides using a different proxy which doesn't forward your IP. I think point 1 is more likely the issue though.